# Variable de Session de objeto List<> en C# - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Guardo en una variable de `Session` elementos de una lista, pero al usarlo en el `_layout`, me dice el siguiente error:

> la funcion foreach no puede funcionar en variable de tipo
>   OpcionUsuarioIndex porque OpcionUsuarioIndex no contiene una
>   definición de instancia publica para GetEnumerator

Aquí está el **Modelo** como lo defino:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PruebaMenu.Models
{
    public class OpcionUsuarioIndex
    {
        public String menu { get; set; }
        public String acceso_op { get; set; }
        public String opcion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

En la **Vista** `_layout`:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        @{string codigo_user = Session["ss_UserCodigo"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
            PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex objClass = (PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex)Session["class"];
           }           

               @foreach (var item in objClass)
               {


               }
    </script>
```

La forma como lleno la lista en el **Controller** es asi:

```
 public ActionResult login_acceso()
        {

                string opcion_rol = Session["ss_Rol"].ToString();
                List<OpcionUsuarioIndex> opcion_permisoUsuario = new List<OpcionUsuarioIndex>();
                DataTable dt_opcionpermiso = new DataTable();

                String sql_permiso = "SELECT opcion,acceso" + opcion_rol + " FROM permisos";

                conexion.conectar();
                MySqlDataAdapter datos2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql_permiso, conexion.con);
                datos2.Fill(dt_opcionpermiso);
                List<String> accesos_list = new List<string>();
                for (int p = 0; p < dt_opcionpermiso.Rows.Count; p++)
                {
                    opcion_permisoUsuario.Add(new OpcionUsuarioIndex
                    {
                        opcion = dt_opcionpermiso.Rows[p][0].ToString(),
                        acceso_op = dt_opcionpermiso.Rows[p][1].ToString()
                    });
                }
                conexion.cerrar();

                Session["class"] = opcion_permisoUsuario;
                return View();

        }
```

Dentro del `foreach`, en el `objClass` me da el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber como puedo solucionar este problema, mi objetivo es poder recorrer una lista que está guardada en una variable de `session` en el `_Layout`. Desde ya gracias.

Comment: De que tipo es la lista que está almacenada en la variable de sesión `Session["class"]`?. Puedes indicar cómo creas la variable `Session["class"]`.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta, gracias por responder, edité la pregunta respondiendo a tu pregunta. Espero que pueda ser mas claro para recibir una solución, gracias.

Comment: a vos te gustaria que recorriera cada propiedad? porque esa clase no es iterable por propiedades

Comment: no deberia ser List<PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex> objClass = (List<PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex>)Session["class"];?

Comment: @gbianchi, tienes razón, yo estaba mal, tal como me dice desapareció el error y ahora voy a probar, parece que tu solución es correcta, por lo menos desapareció el error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu variable `Session["class"]` contiene una lista del tipo `List<OpcionUsuarioIndex>`, debes recuperarla en la Vista de la misma manera:

El código sería el siguiente:

```
@{
     string codigo_user = Session["ss_UserCodigo"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
     List<PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex> objClass = Session["class"] as List<PruebaMenu.Models.OpcionUsuarioIndex>;
 }           
       @foreach (var item in objClass)
       {               
          // AQUÍ RECORRER CADA OBJETO item
          // DEL TIPO OpcionUsuarioIndex
       }
```